# Cakephp $paginate does not show all the results

Tags: cakephp-3.0, pagination

when I do $ paginate even without conditions, I miss 5 results.
when I do a "find all" on the same table I have all the results.

```
$this->paginate = [
        'order' => ['Radars.id' => 'DESC'],
        'contain' => ['Cities', 'Accommodations', 'Users'],   
    ];        
    $radars = $this->paginate($this->Radars);
```

Comment: Given that the sole purpose of pagination is to not fetch all records at once, your problem description is a little ambigous. If you're referring to the total number of records, then keep in mind that containments that are using `INNER` joins can affect that.

Comment: @ndm thanks,that's right. it was a joining problem. I solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually paginate has its own default parameters already defined. Max limit is set to 100 by default.
See the doc for more details
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html